# How to create a extension for the Etar Calender

Tags: java, kotlin

How to create an extension for the Etar Calender in Android Studio? I want that the created event from me to be sent on WhatsApp or Messenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can try these In Android Studio, create a new project and select the "Empty Activity" template.
2. Call the activity "EtarCalendarActivity".
3. In the AndroidManifest.xml file, add the following permissions:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
> ```

4. Also add the following line to the manifest file:

> ```
> <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
> ```

5. In the EtarCalendarActivity.java file, import the following classes:

> ```
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.widget.Toast;
> import com.etar.calendar.EtarCalendar;
> import com.etar.calendar.EtarDatePicker;
> import com.etar.calendar.EtarTimePicker;
> ```

6. Add the following code to the EtarCalendarActivity class:

> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
> ```
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_etar_calendar);
>
> EtarCalendar etarCalendar = (EtarCalendar) findViewById(R.id.etarCalendar);
>
> EtarDatePicker etarDatePicker =
> (EtarDatePicker) findViewById(R.id.etarDatePicker);
>
> EtarTimePicker etarTimePicker =
> (EtarTimePicker) findViewById(R.id.etarTimePicker);
>
> etarCalendar.setListener(new EtarCalendar.Listener() {
> @Override
> public void onDateSelected(EtarDatePicker etarDatePicker,
> EtarDate etarDate) {
> Toast.makeText(
> EtarCalendarActivity.this,
> etarDate.toString(),
> Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onTimeSelected(
> EtarTimePicker etarTimePicker,
> EtarTime etarTime) {
> Toast.makeText(
> EtarCalendarActivity.this,
> etarTime.toString(),
> Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> }
> });
>
> etarDatePicker.setListener(new EtarDatePicker.Listener() {
> @Override
> public void onDateSelected(
> EtarDatePicker etarDatePicker,
> EtarDate etarDate) {
> EtarTimePicker etarTimePicker =
> (EtarTimePicker) findViewById(R.id.etarTimePicker);
> etarDate.set(etarDatePicker.getDate());
> etarTime.set(etarTimePicker.getTime());
> }
> });
>
> etarTimePicker.setListener(new EtarTimePicker.Listener() {
> @Override
> public void onTimeSelected(
> EtarTimePicker etarTimePicker,
> EtarTime etarTime) {
> EtarDatePicker etarDatePicker =
> (EtarDatePicker) findViewById(R.id.etarDatePicker);
> etarDate.set(etarDatePicker.getDate());
> }
> });
>
> }
> ```

7. Run the application.